# How to alternate below code into Bluebird Promise style?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bluebird

All i am almost new to bluebird/promiseA+, and i want to known how to alternate below code of mongoose into bluebird style ?

```
UserUnit.find({ user_id: req.user._id }).populate('unit_id').exec(function (err, units) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err)
    } else {
        a = a + b;
        res.json(units)
    }
})
```

Here is what I tried:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')

Promise.promisifyAll(UserUnit)
Promise.promisifyAll(UserUnit.prototype)

var Promise = require('bluebird')

Promise.promisifyAll(UserUnit)
Promise.promisifyAll(UserUnit.prototype)

UserUnit.findAsync({ user_id : req.user._id })
.spread(function (rs) {
    return Promise.try(function() {
        return rs.populate('unit_id')
    })
}).then(function (units) {
    res.json(units)
}).catch(function (err) {
    if (err) res.send(err)
})
```

Comment: You've repeated the first 4 lines two times.

Answer (score 7):

`UserUnit.find` is not a callback method or even asynchronous so `UserUnit.findAsync` doesn't make sense. You shouldn't need to promisify your own classes you should just have your clasess to return promises to begin with.

If you have promisified mongoose somewhere:

```
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mongoose"));
```

You can do

```
UserUnit.find({ user_id: req.user._id })
    .populate("unit_id")
    .execAsync()
    .then(function(units) {
        res.json(units);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        res.send(err);
    });
```